# Evaluating a sum with constraints on the indices

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

I want to know how to write

$$\sum_{\substack{a,b,c>0 \\ a+b+c=n}} f(a,b,c).$$

as an expression that can be evaluated in Mathematica. I know that I can write the summation

$$\sum_{\substack{a,b >0 \\ a+b=n}} f(a,b)$$

as

```
FullSimplify[Sum[f(a, b), {a, 1, n - a - 1}]]
```

Further, I can write the following code to get the permutations

```
Select[index[n], Length[#] == 3&].
```

but I don't know how to assign values to $a,b,c$ inside the summation code?

Comment: If a,b, and c are integers, then you can use `IntegerPartitions[n, {3}]` and `Permutations[]` to generate all possible (a,b,c) and then total it to get the required.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Yes we can also use >>Select[index[n],Length[#]==3&]. Since I'm new to Mathematica I don't know how to use it inside the summation code. How can we assign values to $a,b,c$ ?

Comment: For three variables, you can still write it in using `Sum[]` like this: `Sum[Sum[f[a, n - c - a, c], {a, 1, n - c - 1}], {c, 1, n - 2}]`